# Nextjs 13.5.4: Parent loading page is overwriting child loading page

Tags: next.js, loading, app-router

I'm using nextjs 13.5.4 with app router. I'm trying to implement different loading.tsx for every page but problem is the parent loading.tsx style is always showing while rendering nested pages with it's own loading.tsx. so when i render a nested page there are multiple loading pages applying before the data been fetch.

Answer (score 4):

I think a good solution is to remove the loading.tsx from the parent route, and then add a suspense with a loader as fallback, like so

```
function page() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
     <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
       <Main />
     </Suspense>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Here, The main async part of the page (all your Nextjs data-fetching logic) can go into Main, Nextjs will stream the components in as soon as the data is available, With this, child routes will no longer have any loading.tsx to inherit from, and might as well use their own dedicated loading.tsx

Answer (score 1):

That's by design of Next.js.

> - Any route segment can optionally define its own Layout. These layouts will be shared across all pages in that segment.
> - Layouts in a route are nested by default. Each parent layout wraps child layouts below it using the React children prop.
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

So if you have a `app/parent/layout.tsx` and `app/parent/child/layout.tsx`:

- When you visit `/parent`, only `parent/layout.tsx` will be applied
- When you visit `/parent/child`, both layouts will be applied, with `parent/child/layout.tsx` wrapped by `parent/layout.tsx`

You can read more about this behaviour here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#nesting-layouts

Comment: yes. are loading.tsx pages work same way? I don't understand how this will be useful then as every nested pages will have multiple loading styles.

Comment: @musa Yes, thats the whole point of nested layouts. Child inheriting from parent layout. If thats not a behaviour you are looking for, you need to check whether it still needs to be a child or not.

Comment: Well it's not exatly the same. We're talking about "loading.tsx" which replaces a page.tsx, not a layout.tsx (the loading doesn't override the layout).

In this case, I don't understand WHY it would support nested feature. That's not like you would be able